# How will i get all the prices in a given ecommerce page because I can only get some of the prices

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The code below only scrapes some of the prices in the given page, how will I scrape every price in the given page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get('https://www.jumia.com.ng/phones-tablets/samsung/?q=samsung+a10')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
content = soup.select('article.prd')
for article in content:
   price = article.find('div', class_='prc')
   print(price)
```

This is the result of the code. If you notice the last sets of div returned are empty and they are not empty in the webpage, how will I go about it?

```
<div class="prc">₦ 49,990</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 51,990</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 53,800</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,000</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 74,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,150</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,200</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 38,990</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,800</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 1,450</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 2,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 4,000</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 2,000</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 4,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 7,000</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 13,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 4,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,850</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,300</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 7,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,999</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,850</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 59,900</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,999</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 5,490</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 2,850</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 80,910</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 59,999</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 3,800</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 80,910</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 75,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 91,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 78,500</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 60,000</div>
<div class="prc">₦ 60,000</div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
<div class="prc"></div>
```

Comment: Might be an idea to download the HTML code and put it somewhere. Maybe in a div? That way the issue could be easily reproduced in the future. I notice that indeed the last couple of "article" tags have a different structure. They correspond to your missing prices. I don't understand why they are empty though for you.

Comment: Exactly, I cant place why there are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The products without prices are *sponsored* products. This content is loaded dynamically via Javascript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see it. You can use this script that will load normal **AND** sponsored products:

```
import re
import json
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.jumia.com.ng/phones-tablets/samsung/?q=samsung+a10'

with requests.session() as s:
    data = json.loads(re.search(r'window.__STORE__=({.*?});', s.get(url).text).group(1))

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

    for product in data['products']:
        print('{:<10} {}'.format(product['prices']['price'], product['name']))

    print('\n * * * SPONSORED: * * *\n')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get('https://www.jumia.com.ng' + data['sponsoredUrl']).content, 'html.parser')
    data = json.loads( soup.select_one('[data-products-spon]')['data-products-spon'] )

    for product in data:
        print('{:<10} {}'.format(product['prices']['price'], product['name']))
```

Prints:

```
₦ 49,990   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB,32GB ROM) Android 9.0, (13MP+2MP)+ 8MP Dual SIM 4000mAh 4G LTE Smartphone - Black
₦ 51,990   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM) Android 9.0 Pie,(13MP+2MP)+8MP,4G LTE, Fingerprint Dual Sim Smartphone - Black
₦ 53,800   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM) - (13MP + 2MP) + 8MP, 4000 MAh 4G LTE, Fingerprint  - BLUE
₦ 3,000    A10S Flip Stand Clear View Case+screen Guard - Black
₦ 74,500   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB,32GB ROM) Android 9.0, (13MP+2MP)+ 8MP Dual SIM 4000mAh 4G LTE Smartphone - Black
₦ 3,150    Galaxy A10s Flip Stand Clear View Case
₦ 3,200    Galaxy A10 Case Luxury Silicone Black
₦ 38,990   A10e Mobile Phone Samsung Exynos 7884 5.83" 2GB 32GB 3000mAh Battery 8.0MP Rear Camera Smartphone
₦ 3,800    Fast Charger And USB Cable For Galaxy Note4,Note Edge,Galaxy Note5,S6,S6edge,S6edge+,S7,S7edge,S8,Galaxy A10,A20,A30
₦ 1,450    Galaxy A10/A20/A30/A50/A70/ 5D Display Screen Protector
₦ 2,500    Galaxy A10/A20/A30/A50/A70/ 5D Display Screen Protector
₦ 4,000    Galaxy A10s Case Luxury Silicone Black
₦ 2,000    Protector For Samsung Galaxy A10/A20/A30/A50/A70
₦ 3,500    A10S Flip Stand Clear View Case
₦ 3,500    A10 Silicone Back Case - Red
₦ 4,500    Galaxy A10 Case Luxury Silicone Black
₦ 3,500    Galaxy A10 Case Luxury Silicone Black - Black
₦ 7,000    Galaxy A10 Silicon Pouch Red
₦ 13,500   Galaxy A10 Clear View Pouch Black
₦ 4,500    Galaxy A10s Tempered Glass (2 PC's)
₦ 3,850    A10S Silicone Back Case - Black
₦ 3,500    Galaxy A10s Case Luxury Silicone Black
₦ 3,300    Galaxy A10 Case Luxury Silicone Black
₦ 7,500    A10S Flip Stand Clear View Case+screen Guard - Black
₦ 3,999    A10 Flip Stand Clear View Case- Black
₦ 3,500    A10 Silicone Back Case - Black
₦ 3,850    A10S Silicone Back Case - Black
₦ 59,900   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB,32GB ROM) Android 9.0, (13MP+2MP)+ 8MP Dual SIM 4000mAh 4G LTE Smartphone - Red (BF19)
₦ 3,999    A10S Flip Stand Clear View Case- Black
₦ 5,490    Galaxy A10s Clear View Case +Full Screen Glass
₦ 2,850    Charger Cord Cable For Samsung Galaxy A10E A50 A20 Note 10 S20 Plus Ultra 5G A51 A71,LG G7 G8 V40 V50 G9 V60 Thinq,G6,V30 V20,3A USB Type C Data Cable,Fast Charge Charging Phone Power Wire
₦ 80,910   GALAXY A10s (6.2'', 2GB/32GB, Andriod 9.0 Pie, 13MP+2MP Back Camera, 8MP Selfie Camera, 4000mAh, 4G - Blue
₦ 59,999   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM) Android 9.0 Pie,(13MP+2MP)+8MP,4G LTE, Fingerprint Dual Sim Smartphone - Black
₦ 3,800    Galaxy A 10 Case 
₦ 80,910   GALAXY A10s (6.2'', 2GB/32GB, Andriod 9.0 Pie, 13MP+2MP Back Camera, 8MP Selfie Camera, 4000mAh, 4G - Black
₦ 75,500   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inches Screen Display Android 9.0 Dual Sim SmartPhone - 2GB RAM 32GB Internal Storage
₦ 91,500   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inches Screen Display Android 9.0 Dual Sim SmartPhone - 2GB RAM 32GB Internal Storage
₦ 78,500   Galaxy A10s 6.2-Inch (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM) Android 9.0 Pie, (13MP + 2MP) + 8MP 4G LTE, Fingerprint Dual Sim - Blue
₦ 60,000   Galaxy A10s 6.2' (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM), 4000 MAh 4G LTE, Dual Sim Smartphone - Blue
₦ 60,000   Galaxy A10s 6.2' (2GB RAM, 32GB ROM), 4000 MAh 4G LTE, Dual Sim Smartphone - Black

 * * * SPONSORED: * * *

₦ 2,790    Galaxy Fast Charger For S9 - White
₦ 65,000    Galaxy Note 10+/10plus S-view Flip Cover(sensor)
₦ 3,599    Galaxy Fast Adaptive Charger For Charging Samsung Phones
₦ 7,500    Galaxy A5   Replacement Battery
₦ 6,000    Bluetooth Neckband (NA08)
₦ 12,500   Galaxy Tab A, 8.0 Inch Guard-Full Edged Glass Protector
₦ 3,500    Galaxy S8+ Plus Silicone Back Case (Improved Version)
₦ 7,000    Galaxy S9 Plus Flip Standing Clear View Smart Cover
```

---

EDIT: Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Your code missed the #58,000 product. Please check and reconfirm. Thanks

Comment: @AchebePeter Do you mean price `58,000`? I see no product with that price...

Comment: pls can you check out this website and you will see it. https://www.jumia.com.ng/phones-tablets/samsung/?q=samsung+a10. Thanks Andrej

Comment: @AchebePeter No, I don't see any product with price 58,000 - only discounted from 58,000 to 53,800 (see the screenshot it edit).

Comment: Yea, I see the product you talking about. But pls check down the webpage of phones with price, 63500, 56000,58000,62500 are not in the scraped data.

Comment: @AchebePeter Maybe this is sponsored content that is different for you - but I don't see it. Do you see the same products I have in screenshot?

Comment: I just checked the website using chrome, i didnt see the products. Do you have a possible answer as to why i see these products using microsoft edge but not in chrome

Comment: @AchebePeter It all depends on the server, what page is returned. You can try to change the `User-Agent` HTTP header and see if the results are different.